# FOSUserBundle undefined method getName();

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to install FOSUserBundle for the first time. After following the steps, I tried executing `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. This gives me the following error. I can't understand why it's looking for `getName()`, it's not shown in the bundle in examples online.

```
   PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method  music\userBundle\userBundle::getName() in /home/me/public_html/music/app/bootstrap.php.cache on line 2505
```

my bundle:

```php
<?php
// src/userBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace userBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, try to clear cache manually remove `dev` and `prod` folders in `app/cache`

Comment: Could you show your `music\userBundle\userBundle` class content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the root directory of your application is interpreted as namespace.

The error output say **music\userBundle::getName()**, but call getName() on your entity name should be **userBundle\User::getName()** .

I think you have to re-build your application using the following class architecture :

```
YourNamespace\UserBundle
```

So, you entity should become

```
YourNamespace\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

and

```
YourNamespaceUserBundle::User
```

If you can, post your config.yml and security.yml files

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to make sure that you include your bundle in `AppKernel.php`, also should review your namespaces, during best practices your namespace should contain vendor name, bundle name, directory to class, so u should consider to set your namespace to something like this:

```
namespace music\userBundle\Entity;
```

Because for now it looks like you do something wrong:

```
music\userBundle\userBundle::getName()
```

and

```
namespace userBundle\Entity;
```

And after installing new bundles (or after any important changes) dont forget to clear you by cli command or manually. Try this, and if it doesnt helps then we will go deeper to your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry seems like named the userBundle wrong, as following a video tutorial I did it manually, and forgot the extends part.

```
 namespace music\userBundle;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

   class userBundle extends Bundle
  {
  }
```